# Iron-router is not working in latest meteor version?

Tags: meteor

Hi i am done my project in meteor 0.8. version using iron-router for rendering now if it is updated the project website not coming only blank screen is showing how can i solve for this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove iron-router package and install it again:

```
meteor add iron:router
```